# Why isnt my Animation not working?

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me ? I reconstructed my problem in CodePen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWaXaO

```css
.dog {
  animation-name: dog;
}

@keyframes dog {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/PB0101_HERO-Dog-TreatsRawhide-20160818?$sclp-banner-main_large$" class="dog">
```

Why isnt the Animation on the image not working ?

thanks for help.

Comment: Code is convention. Before you use it, you're supposed to research what it means, what are the available options, eventually going through some examples and prerequisites. Your question shows no such research effort. Exaggerating a bit, it's pretty much like speaking to your page, yelling at it to "Animate!". It only understands the options that are part of the convention. So go through docs and examples, start from something that works, change the values, see how that goes. If others do this for you, you won't learn anything, and I believe that's what you're trying to do, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum, you need to specify an `animation-duration`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration

> A value of 0s, which is the default value, indicates that no animation should occur.

```css
.dog {
  animation-name: dog;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes dog {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/PB0101_HERO-Dog-TreatsRawhide-20160818?$sclp-banner-main_large$" class="dog">
```